# How to implement a flexible grid column layout system in QT widgets?

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm a designer working with QT widgets which uses dockable widgets, and I'm trying to setup a grid column system for the buttons and elements to be proportional to rearrange properly when these widgets are re-sized, something like http://thesquaregrid.com/ or http://960.gs/.

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: You can probably use a QGridLayout to manage everything. You can also inherit QLayout and create your own layout. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html. The flow layout provides a good example. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html